# Как починить сокеты питон??? Python

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, ip, client

**Server.py**

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

clients: list[socket.socket] = []

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server:
    server.bind(("31.200.237.14", 50033))
    server.listen(16)


    def client_accepter():
        while True:
            user, addr = server.accept()
            print(f"user connected: {addr}\n")
            clients.append(user)

    def sender():
        while True:
            message = input("\n").encode()
            for user in clients:
            user.send(message)

    print("Starting server...")
    Thread(target=client_accepter).start()
    sender()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket() as client:

    client.connect(("31.200.237.14", 50033))
    print("Connected to server succesfully!")
    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024).decode()
        if data:
            print(data)
```

Ставлю внешний ip компа друга, он белый (и друг тоже), при попытке запустить

```
OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен
```

Во всех туторах про сокеты говорят, мол можно и во внешку сервер поставить, и переписываться с другом и т.д. и т.п. Но никто ни разу не показал как. Покажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ваше устройство-сервер было видно вне локальной сети, у роутеров есть функция проброса портов: если трафик идёт по определённому порту, то он перенаправляется с роутера на устройство, которое вы укажете.

Пример настройки проброса портов для роутера TP-Link:

1. Заходим на сайт роутера (http://192.168.0.1 или http://192.168.1.1) и вводим данные для входа.
2. Дополнительные настройки -> Переадресация NAT -> Виртуальные серверы -> Добавить
3. Необходимые поля для заполнения — **"внешний порт"** (порт, к которому обращается клиент), **"внутренний IP-адрес"** (IP-адрес сервера в локальной сети) и **"внутренний порт"** (порт сервера, на который будет направлен трафик, можно написать внешний порт)
   [image: Интерфейс настройки виртуального сервера]

Учтите, что IP-адрес сервера нужно прописывать только в клиенте, у сервера же, в команде `server.bind`, строку адреса лучше оставить пустой:
`server.bind(("", 50033))`